# Swift detect address in UITextField

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I am building an app that needs to be able to search for a location without them entering the address in any particular format. is there any way I could detect this in swift, and break the address down into components (like city, zip) for me to use as strings? Thanks

Comment: `UITextField` itself can detect address, but breaking down into components requires extra logic. Do you want to support English address only? or do you need to support all languages?

Comment: For now just English, but I would like to make it compatible with other languages in a future version.

Comment: I Think You Should Have A Large Database Of All Possible Cities, Countries, Streets And ... To Detect An Address. In Some Cases There Are Streets With City Names. This Needs A Heavy Coding :D

Comment: @DaniM.Smith this task is not simple. Lots of cases to consider even just English addresses. Easiest approach is to separate different text fields for different components.